# how to make logging.logger to behave like print

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Let's say I got this [logging.logger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) instance:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('root')
FORMAT = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Problem comes when I try to use it like the builtin print with a dynamic number of arguments:

```
>>> logger.__class__
<class 'logging.Logger'>
>>> logger.debug("hello")
[<stdin>:1 -             <module>() ] hello
>>> logger.debug("hello","world")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python2711\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 853, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "c:\Python2711\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 726, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "c:\Python2711\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 465, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "c:\Python2711\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 329, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Logged from file <stdin>, line 1
```

How could i emulate the print behaviour still using logging.Logger?

Comment: just enclose params in brackets like logger.debug(("hello","world")) for example

Comment: Andrey: Mmm,  ok,  I can make a fast search&replace from all my prints following your  pattern, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, define a function that accepts `*args` and then `join` them in your call to `logger`:

```
def log(*args, logtype='debug', sep=' '):
    getattr(logger, logtype)(sep.join(str(a) for a in args))
```

I added a `logtype` for flexibility here but you could remove it if not required.

Comment: Excellent! I've added my answer based on your code, thanks ;)

Comment: ... `"{}".format(a)` is really just an ugly and convoluted way of writing `str(a)`... Also `(f(x) for x in sequence)` is just `map(f, sequence)` if you like functional style.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapper based on @Jim's original answer:

```
import logging
import sys

_logger = logging.getLogger('root')
FORMAT = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class LogWrapper():

    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def info(self, *args, sep=' '):
        self.logger.info(sep.join("{}".format(a) for a in args))

    def debug(self, *args, sep=' '):
        self.logger.debug(sep.join("{}".format(a) for a in args))

    def warning(self, *args, sep=' '):
        self.logger.warning(sep.join("{}".format(a) for a in args))

    def error(self, *args, sep=' '):
        self.logger.error(sep.join("{}".format(a) for a in args))

    def critical(self, *args, sep=' '):
        self.logger.critical(sep.join("{}".format(a) for a in args))

    def exception(self, *args, sep=' '):
        self.logger.exception(sep.join("{}".format(a) for a in args))

    def log(self, *args, sep=' '):
        self.logger.log(sep.join("{}".format(a) for a in args))

logger = LogWrapper(_logger)
```

Comment: In this way, the %lineno will always be  the one in LogWrapper, which might be unwanted.

Comment: dont forget to add **kwargs to all functions

Answer (score -1):

Set sys.stdout as the stream for your logging.

e.g.
`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout`)

Comment: I've tried it out with python 3.5.1 and that still crashes `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: If had that happen before to me, the line that caused it did something like: `('{} {}', variable1, variable2)`. When changed to `'{} {}'.format(variable1, variable2)` fixed it for me.